Is there any way to build a Modern Chart using calculated form fields?
I have a form driven by a query, but the display of the query results are quantified with calculated form fields.  My manager wants visuals of the totals, but when I try to create the Modern Charts for it, the only options for sourcing the chart data are tables and queries.
Is there anyway to display the form fields' data on the chart?
Thank you for any assistance.
I attempted to type input the form field titles into the Row Source, but it only returned errors.

I think the answer to your question is "no".
